# Regex for string with quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which is in below format

```
Key1="value1" Key2="value2" Key3="value3"
```

I want to extract extract keys and values from the string.
"value" can contain new line, single quote, double quotes etc.

```
s = @"interactionId=""1f367d11-1f9d-4ff4-9fa3-e793dc0f7fe4"" timestamp=""2018-08-07T18:25:38.8309683Z"" textPayload=""#"" activityJson=""{
  ""type"": ""conversationUpdate"",
  ""id"": ""e3abig35e395"",
  ""timestamp"": ""2018-08-07T18:25:15.415+00:00"",
  ""localTimestamp"": ""2018-08-07T11:25:15-07:00""";
```

I was able to write this. but it does work when Value has quotes in it.

```
var ItemRegex = new Regex(@"(?<key>[^, ]+)=(?<value>[""].+?[""]|[^ ]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

result = 
                ItemRegex.Matches(message)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    key = m.Groups["key"].ToString().Trim('"'),
                    value = m.Groups["value"].ToString().Trim('"')
                })
                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.key, kvp => kvp.value);
```

How can I escape quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the input data; the value of `activityJson` has unescaped quotes in it, making it hard to determine where the data ends.

If you are able to change the input data, you should definitely do so.

As an example, in xml double quotes are escaped with `&quot;`:

```
<data attrib="value with &quot;quotes&quot;" />
```